# Highlighting text?

Tags: pdf, epub

I've been searching for a while to know how Highlighting text (books on PDF, epub, mobi) works programmatically, what kind of code or tech stays behind this feature, yet I couldn't find anything. If you know, please share any hint here.

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

For PDFs you can highlight text by adding a highlight text markup annotation:

> ### 12.5.6.10 Text Markup Annotations
>
> Text markup annotations shall appear as highlights, underlines, strikeouts (all PDF 1.3), or jagged (“squiggly”)
>   underlines (PDF 1.4) in the text of a document. When opened, they shall display a pop-up window containing
>   the text of the associated note. Table 179 shows the annotation dictionary entries specific to these types of
>   annotations.
>
> *([ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

You can find details in Table 179. For a specification of annotations in general, read the earlier subsections of section 12.5 Annotations.

---

Alternatively you can also add the highlighting into the page content. This has the disadvantage that others cannot easily change the highlight (which actually might be an advantage in some use cases). Depending on the PDF viewers to support you might be forced to do this, though.